# Return search results from Rails API in Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, factory

I have a rails API that will run a GET request and return search results. I want to hook this up to my angular app on the front end.

My Factory looks like this:

```
app.factory('results', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('/droplets/search?search=' + searchparam + '.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

My first problem is that I don't know how to pass the search param to the factory. My form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" name="searchDropletsForm" ng-submit="findDroplets">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input ng-model="search_keyword" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Droplets">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in the controller I have:

```
app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', 'results', function($scope, results) {
  results(search_keyword).success(function(data) {
    $scope.results = data;
  });
}]);
```

The problem here is knowing how to pass the parameter from the form, which comes from the ng-model="search_keyword", into the controller and then into the factory so I can perform the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory needs to change slightly:

```
app.factory('results', ['$http', function($http) {
  return { 
    search : function (searchparam) { 
      return $http.get('/droplets/search?search=' + searchparam + '.json')
    }
  }
}]);
```

Your controller needs to change too:

```
app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', 'results', function($scope, results) {
  results.search($scope.search_keyword).success(function(data) {
    $scope.results = data;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I also needed to change my ng-submit to submit() and then put $scope.submit = function ...